# How do you prove that $0$ is the only value for $x$ where $\sin x = x$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the best way to prove that $x$ can only equal $0$. Could you graph $\sin x$ and $\sin (-x)$ on eachother?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac d {dx} (x-\sin x)=1-\cos x \geq 0$ so $x-\sin x$ is non-decreasing. If $\sin x=x$ for some $x>0$ then $y-\sin y$ would be $0$ for all $y$ between $0$ and $x$ which would make the  derivative $1-\cos x $ also $0$ there and this is a contradiction. Hence $\sin x <x$ for all $x >0$. Can you handle $x <0$?

Comment: so x does not equal 0 as an exact value?

Comment: I have proved that $\sin x =x$ and $x >0$ implies $x=0$. I leave it to you to prove the same thing when $x<0$. The conclusion is $\sin x =x$ iff $x=0$. @Mathwiz

Comment: The question that I have been given to sole is exactly "Is there a value x such that sin x = x?" Is graphing the best way to solve that x=0

Comment: No, graphs don't prove anything. Using Calculus is the best way.

Comment: Is there any other way to prove other than calculus as I have not gotten up to the stage to use calculus yet.